# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException with Query (Spring mvc)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have got a Query. (It's my full DAO method)

```
@Override
public void addUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
    Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    String query = "insert into 'user_roles'('role','username') values(%s,%s)"; 
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List roleAdd = session.createQuery(String.format(query, "'ROLE_USER'", "'acid'")).list();

    tx.commit();

}
```

And it gives me an exception

```
type Exception report message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: expecting IDENT, found ''user_roles'' near line 1, column 13 

[insert into 'user_roles'('role','username') values('ROLE_USER','acid')]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found ''user_roles'' near line 1, column 13 

[insert into 'user_roles'('role','username') values('ROLE_USER','acid')] description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Comment: This code should not compile. I think you made a copy paste mistake somewhere? You're defining the variable 'query' twice.

Comment: @mhlz, oh! thanx a lot!  Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("insert into spring_social_db.user_roles(role,username) - This String musn't be here!

Comment: Try taking the single quotation marks off of the table name.

Comment: @bcholmes, thanx for an answer! but it doesn't help

Comment: The code has changed, and it looks like the line that starts with `String query = ` is no longer applicable. Is there a different exception message now?

Comment: @bcholmes, " Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 43 [insert into user_roles('role','username') values('ROLE_USER','acid')]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 43 [insert into user_roles('role','username') values('ROLE_USER','acid')]"

Comment: Hm. It seems to be complaining about `values` now. Which DB are you using? And what happens if you put a space after `values`?

Comment: @bcholmes, I'm using MySQL Database. After putting a space after 'values' it gives me next error "Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 43 [insert into user_roles('role','username') values ('ROLE_USER','acid')]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 43 [insert into user_roles('role','username') values ('ROLE_USER','acid')]"

Comment: Hm. The edit that was made a moment ago switched from `createSQLQuery` to `createQuery`. The example looks like you want SQL, but you're invoking the method that's expecting HQL. Can you toggle it back to `createSQLQuery`?

Comment: I changed to `createQuery` and it gives me "e Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [S1009]; error code [0]; could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet"

Comment: So now the code is trying to get a list of results (which it builds from a result set). But your SQL statement is an insert statement, which doesn't produce a result set. Your line should be `int resultCount = session.createSQLQuery(String.format(query, "'ROLE_USER'", "'acid'")).executeUpdate()`.

Comment: @bcholmes, thanx a lot! It works

Comment: Cool. I've added the revised code as an answer, below. If this solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your method should look like:

```
@Override
public void addUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
    Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    String query = "insert into 'user_roles'('role','username') values(%s,%s)"; 
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    int resultCount = session.createSQLQuery(String.format(query, "'ROLE_USER'", "'acid'")).executeUpdate();

    tx.commit();
}
```